# What happens if a team returns a blocked extra point a long way, but not all the way to the end zone?

Tags: rules, american-football

Suppose a team blocks an extra point. I realize that if the defense returns the ball to the end zone, it counts as a two-point score. However, what if the defense returns the ball to, say, the opposing 20-yard line? Is that the usual kickoff, or does the defense have the option to keep the ball at the 20?

I suspect that they don't, but I can't find any place that spells out the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens if a team returns a blocked extra point a long way, but not all the way to the end zone?

The ball is considered dead, and the rules regarding what takes place after a try (a kickoff) is put into effect.

---

As posted [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/20145), an extra point is defined as a "try."

A specific rule reference for the NCAA regarding the results of a try can be found at Rule 8, Section 3, Article 2 (specifically point d2):

> d. The try ends when:
>
> 2. The ball is dead by rule (A.R. 8-3-2-IV and VI).

A specific rule reference for the NCAA regarding what takes place after a try can be found at Rule 8, Section 3, Article 6:

> **After a try, the ball shall be put in play by a kickoff** or at the
>   succeeding spot in extra periods. The team scoring the six-point touchdown
>   shall kick off.

---

A specific rule reference for the NFL regarding the results of a try can be found at Rule 11, Section 3, Article 2 (specifically point e):

> During a Try, the following shall apply:
>
> (e)  The Try ends when ...  the ball is dead by rule.

A specific rule reference for the NFL regarding what takes place after a try can be found at [Rule 3, Section 18, Article 5, Item 1](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2018-nfl-rulebook/#section-18-kicks):

> A Kickoff is a kick that puts the ball in play at the start of each
>   half, at the start of overtime, **after each Try**, and after a successful
>   field goal.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to stay at the 20.

The outcomes of an extra point attempt are

- scoring the extra point
- returned for a safety by the defence
- scoring a safety by the offence

Anything else is considered just a miss and play restarts as specified by the rules.